# How to add Value on Top of Asp.net Drop-down through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I got requirement to prepend values in dropdown through javascript. The dropdown is already bind with datasource.

Answer (score 0):

**Aspx:**

```
<body onload="Prepend()">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlnames" runat="server"DataTextField="Id" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function Prepend(){

            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = "111";
            option.value = "3";
            option.selected=true;

            var parent = document.getElementById("<%=ddlnames.ClientID %>")
            parent.insertBefore(option, parent.firstChild);

 }
```